# Take image src from image tag into string variable

Tags: asp.net

I have some html text which sometimes contains an image, e.g.

```
<img src="imagename.jpg" alt="something" />
```

I know how to remove the whole image tag from the text, but I was looking to take the image SRC out of the text (and stored it in a DB).

There is only one image in every piece of text, so just looking the src as a string variable.

Anyone know how that could be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the text stored in a database or something? This sounds like a job for a regular expression. Which .NET language are you using?

Comment: I'm using VB.net. Yeah the text is stored in a DB actually...but when I display the text I don;t want the image stuck in the middle...want to put in somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to extract the src attrib into a variable, and then have jquery make an ajax call to the page, passing the src value.

```
var src = $('.someClassForImg').attr('src');
```

Alternatively, if you're using web forms, you could just pass the full  tag like you said you are able to, and then just extract the src portion. Tim suggested regular expressions which could work

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

...
  Dim pattern As String = "(src=\s*\"(.+?)\")" 
  Dim html As String = <img html>
     Dim src() As String = Regex.Split(html, pattern))
  Next
```

Then again, if you're using webforms, why not just use the Image control, which you can runat server and just pull the ImageURL property?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image(v=vs.100).aspx

I guess it depends on how your project is configured, which we would need more information on to determine the best approach. :)

Comment: Ok, when I said I could remove the image tag I meant using a regular expression I could delete it completely out of the html, not get it into a string in it's own right. I've just noticed the image is always between two < p > tag, so I might just get the image tag as a substring, then extract src using the regular expression like you've mentioned.